# Is there a case where "[^xy]" is not equal to "(?!x|y)."?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on my own JavaScript library to support new metacharacters and features for regular expressions, and I'd like to find a case where `[^xy]` is not equivalent to `(?!x).` (or more specifically `(?:(?!x|y).)`).

Take the example text: `"abc\n"`

Say I want to emulate a Perl regex: `/\A.{3}\Z/s`

With the singleline flag, the JavaScript regex should be equivalent to: `/^[\s\S]{3}\n*$(?!\s)/` (`\A` becomes `^`, `.` becomes `[\s\S]`, `\Z` becomes `\n*$(?!\s)`)

Now, `/^.{3}$/` would fail, but `/^[\s\S]{3}\n*$(?!\s)/` would capture "abcabc" (same as the Perl regex)

Since `\Z` contains more than just a metacharacter, emulating `[^\Z]` would seem to be more difficult.

Take the example text: `"abcabc\n"`

The proposed JavaScript regex for the Perl regex `/.{3}[^\Za]/g` would be `.{3}(?:(?!\n*$(?!\s)|a).)/g`

Both will match `"bcab"`

So, finally, I pose the question again. Is there a case where `[^xy]` is not equivalent to `(?:(?!x|y).)` with such a scenario, perhaps in a more complex regular expression where a lookahead would change the scenario?

Comment: `/^[\s\S]{3}\n*$(?!\s)/.exec("abcabc\n")` does not match for me, and does not give `abcabc` as you suggest

Comment: Nor does the perl regex `/\A.{3}\Z/s` match `"abcabc\n"`, as you claim it does...

Comment: Correct. I changed some things around and forgot to edit them. The first scenario uses the text "abc\n" and the second scenario uses the text "abcabc\n". I've made the edit to the main post.

Comment: `[^\Z]` is not a thing, because `\Z` is not a character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a case where `[^xy]` is not equal to `(?!x|y).`?

Only the one you have already described: The JS dot doesn't match newlines, and needs to be replaced with `[\s\S]`.

> `\Z` becomes `\n$(?!\s)`

That looks wrong. After the end of the string (`\z`/`$`) there never will be anything, regardless whether whitespace or not. Afaik, `\Z` is a zero-width-assertion (it doesn't consume the newline(s)) and should be equivalent to

```
(?=\n*$)
//   ^ not sure whether ? or *
```

> Since `\Z` contains more than just a metacharacter, emulating `[^\Z]` would seem to be more difficult.

What do you mean by "metacharacter"? It's a zero-width-assertion, and doesn't make much sense in a character class. I'd guess it's either a syntax error, or will be interpreted literally (unescaped) as `[^Z]`.

Comment: Typo: \Z becomes \n*$(?!\s). In Perl, \Z is equivalent to \n*\z. \z is true at the end of a string only. Therefore, if \z is $(?!\s), then \Z is \n*$(?!\s). It seems like I've begun to over-think things with this whole "conversion" idea. You're completely right about [^\Z] becoming [^Z]. I think I need a break from programming, thanks for the insight. :)

Comment: @JoeySchooley the point is that that `\n` is not included in the match. So the `\n` belongs in a lookahead as well (and I'm not so sure about the star after the `\n`)

Comment: I made an edit in the above comment but it looks like you beat me. Thanks for looking into the actual problem of my reasoning.

Comment: Oh I think I understand now what you meant by the `(?=\s)` after `$` - it's to ensure correct matching in multiline mode. Actually I don't know much about that (never used it in JS), so I may be wrong

Answer (score 9):

For input string `"x\na"`, the 2 regexps give different outputs, because `.` doesn't match newlines.

```
console.log("x\na".match(/(?:(?!x|y).)/))
["a", index: 2, input: "x↵a"]
console.log("x\na".match(/[^xy]/))
["↵", index: 1, input: "x↵a"]
```

If you change `.` to `[\s\S]`, the output is identical in this case:

```
console.log("x\na".match(/(?:(?!x|y)[\s\S])/))
["↵", index: 1, input: "x↵a"]
```

I cannot think of any other case right now.

Answer (score 4):

`[^xy]` will match `\n`. `(?!x|y).` will not match `\n` by default (because `.` does not match `\n`)

I do not believe javascript has a "dotall" or "single-line" modifier, but with new versions of each browser hitting every couple months, I've lost track.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, you should use `[\s\S]` instead of `.` in the replacement. Otherwise, if you are doing that transformation just via the literal strings, there are a few more things to take care of. In particular, meta characters and escape sequences:

```
[^*)] => (?!\*|\))[\s\S]
```

But I guess you'll need to take care of parsing and writing meta-characters specially anyway.

The trickiest one is probably `\b` though, because it's a character (backspace) in character classes and a word boundary outside. So in the replacement, you'd have to go with an octal or  hexadecimal escape:

```
[^a\b] => (?!a|\10)[\s\S] 
    or => (?!a|\x08)[\s\S]
```

Other than that, the two should always be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

A case where the format `[^xy]` is not the same as `(?:(?!x|y).)` would be where x was a zero width assertion rather then an actual character like:

Given this sample text: `ab-yz`

Regex: `[^\by]`  Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/ERKrqyeAs9

Returns:

```
[0] => a
[1] => b
[2] => -
[3] => z
```

Whereas

Regex: `(?:(?!\b|y).)` example: http://www.rubular.com/r/V5RdyQEQo5

Returns:

```
[0] => b
[1] => z
```

Other non equivalent expressions, these largely focus on the fact that same syntax has different meenings inside or outside the character class:

- `[^^y]` yields a,b,-,z is not equal to `(?:(?!^|y).)` yields b,-,z
- `[^.y]` yields a,b,-,z is not equal to `(?:(?!.|y).)` yields nothing

Or you could try this in unicode nugget in Perl: http://ideone.com/2xMfkQ

```
print "\ncapture\n";
@m = ("ss" =~ m/^(?:(?!\xDF|y).)+$/ui ); 
print for @m;

print "\nclass\n";
@m = ("ss" =~ m/^[^\xDFy]+$/ui) ; 
print for @m;
```

Yields:

```
capture

class
1
```

Comment: What does a word boundary in a character class mean to you?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything to me, however Joey's question was `I'd like to find a case where [^xy] is not equivalent (?:(?!x|y).)).` and this is a grammatically correct expression which yields a distinctly different result.

Comment: Well `[^\by]` is not grammatically correct for me. In the result you're getting it is interpreted as `[^by]`, which *is* equivalent to `(?!b|y).`

Comment: I updated my answer to cover your issue. I think your understanding of how a character class works may be suspect.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it is - that's why I was asking for the meaning of the word boundary in a character class. Your demo indicates it is completely ignored, as if it was `[^y]`

Comment: The \b in the negated character class isn't ignored, instead it matches the backspace character. For the other expression `(?:(?!\b|y).)` when the regex engine encounters a word boundary the `\b` matches as yes because the next thing is a word boundary, then causes the negative lookahead to fail because of the positive match, that forces the the dot to not get tested. But because the dot really tests real characters the characters after the word break `a`, `-`, and `y` are essentially skipped. Bottom line, you can't test for a word boundary in a character class, forcing different results.